# CakePhp 3 - create new project

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to initiate a new app and the installer doesn't work.

My php version : 5.6.25

Composer is updated (in www folder)

I tried (my folder app is www/product/app) :

```
php ../../composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app app
```

And I get this message:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package cakephp\app with stability stable.
```

Any idea ?
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have all the requirements outlined in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements). You need more than just an up to date version of PHP.

Comment: Yes, I copied the 4 icu*.dll files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to install `CakePHP`, let me recommand [`Oven`](https://github.com/CakeDC/oven) created by the CakePHP community to help install Cakephp easilly

here is a [demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL1nuOMXwLY)